# column separation lines now showing up in table

Tags: tables

I have the following code that produces the table that is shown. What I am trying to do is to get the fourth and fifth column titles vertically aligned at the top. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{| m{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |} \hline
    \multirow{3}{1.7cm}{Data Set} &%
    \multicolumn{3}{c |}{Raw Data} &%
    Offline Processing Time &
    Index Size (KB)\\ \cline{2-4}
%
    & %
    RDF N3 File SizeKB (sec)    &%
    Number of Triples &%
    Number of Entities\\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Better don't use them (vertical lines) at all!*

I think your problem is missing vertical lines. You have to use the ampersands even if those cells are empty, like

```
Number of Entities & & \\    \hline
```

You are done as those titles are already aligned at the top.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand what you mean by "Better don't use them at all"

Comment: @ozsu have a look at the `booktabs` package

Comment: @ozsu: They are not considered as good typographical practice as they reduce readability. See cmhughe's comment above about `booktab manual.

Comment: Got it. Learning booktabs is on my list of things to do, but I'm trying to finish a paper first. Thanks much.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the desired layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{| m{2cm} | x{2cm} | x{2cm} | x{2cm} | x{2cm} | x{2cm} |} \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Data Set} &%
    \multicolumn{3}{c |}{Raw Data} &%
    \multirow{3}{2cm}{Offline Processing Time} &
    \multirow{3}{2cm}{Index Size (KB)}\\ \cline{2-4}
%
    & %
    RDF N3 File SizeKB (sec)    &%
    Number of Triples &%
    Number of Entities & &\\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks: the lines were missing because you didn't complete the columns in the last row (adding the necessary `&` characters). Also, since you have narrow columns, it is better to have the contents `\ragedright`, so I changed your p{} columns to x{} columns (adding `\arraybackslash`).

You should consider not using vertical rules in your tables; the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package discusses this and helps you to create better looking tables.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. I was going to use the x{} only after I solved this problem, but I missed the \arraybackslash. Thanks again.